# Is there an api to allow the user to update the app from within the app?

Tags: ios

Some new users may not know how to use the app store for updating apps. Is there a way from within the app I can provide a button that triggers updating the app ?

Comment: Its hard for me to imagine someone whou wouldn't know how to update an app via AppStore, since it displays badges. But to answer your question - no you cannot trigger an update yourself, this is a users choice - all you can do is is notify your user that a new version is available (though you'd need to support this yourself too, Apple doesn't provide any API for this AFAIK), and maybe display some kind of tutorial. But unless your users are elderly (no offence) or otherwise non-technical people, I think this would be an overkill.

Comment: @Losiowaty Unfortunately, almost half the global population does not use smartphones. Perhaps in your country many people do, but even amongst those who do use smartphone (and even younger people), there are many who simply don't know use any of the features besides email and phone calls.

Comment: Here is a random statistic I googled for you: https://www.statista.com/statistics/330695/number-of-smartphone-users-worldwide/ . Here is another one: http://www.businessinsider.com/how-many-people-own-smartphones-around-the-world-2016-2?IR=T

Comment: Well, if the target audience of your app are these people, you should be more worried about how to get them a smartphone (and an expensive one, since we are talking about iPhones) and how to get them to discover and install your app in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in way to do this.

If you have a way of detecting when a newer version is out (e.g. your server reports the version number of the latest version), then you could just direct users to your app's App Store page when they have an old version — just use `-[UIApplication openURL:]` to open your app's App Store URL, and it'll transfer them to the App Store app.

But as Losiowaty's comment mentions, this is not a thing you should worry about. Most people have automatic app updates turned on. This really is a non-issue.